# Can I write to the Description field of a Google Calendar event?

Tags: api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to write into the Description-field of a Google Calendar event using the Google Calendar API. I know it's possible to do for the Where-field (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/location-autocomplete-for/kofcojkjfdobdmnijbkabkjijkdkpnla) but I'm not sure it's doable for the Description-field. I've read the whole Google Calendar API and can't find anything. Does anybody know if I can write to the Description field?

Comment: Should probably share the code you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

The description field is called "description" and it represents the long textual description in the event's body. See
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource

There is also a "title" which is the short title of the event.

Comment: is there anyway to style this description? like adding a line break or having a bold text etc?

Comment: Yes, just used HTML